# SPDataSource + Missing reference in SharePoint 2013 project

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a project built in SharePoint 2013. I have a SPDataSource as Base class in my project. I have a reference to the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll file but still this SPDataSource and SPDataSourceView are giving me error.

Missing Namespace error

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SPDataSource' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Can anybody tell me why is this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project from inside visual studio from the Templates -> Office/SharePoint -> SharePoint 2013 Empty project.

From there compare the references between that and your project.

Comment: I am sure about the SharePoint dll is correct. I have tried to refrence directly reference it from the ISAPI folder as well but still no luck

Comment: Can you paste a snip of the code or the Solution explorer from visual studio?